# Save csv file from HttpClient post response

Tags: angular, csv, angular-httpclient

I have a website where a user can request some data as a csv-file. The data is then returned as and should be downloaded/saved to a file.

I am sending a post request and subscribing, but it seems to be failing in the catch method every time.

The request header, removed authorization and such:

```
POST /api/@£$ HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 144
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://@£$
Authorization: @£$
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;
```

> with a body containing parameters, so the response is correct.

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Request-Context: 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export_20181120_103716.csv
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: 
Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 10:37:16 GMT
```

Am I missing something vital? Do I need to set the response type? this api will only return csv-file data so don't really need to check the file type.

EDIT:
Adding the code sending the request.

```
dataExport(parameters) {

    const send = {
        'id': parameters.ids,
        'from': parameters.from,
        'to': parameters.to
    };

    this.adalService.post(url, send,
  { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) })
        .do(() => { this.success('success'); })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error(error);
            return Observable.of(null);
        })
        .subscribe(r => {
            const blob = new Blob([r], {type: 'text/csv'});
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(url);
        });

}
```

> EDIT: added `responseType: 'text'` to the post-request. This does not trigger the catch due to wrong reponse format. Is this the correct type? typescript did not let me use text/csv or application/csv. And im worried that when the file gets realy big, a blob will not have enough room to save the data.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more than that. 200 answers means everything went well, but we can't see if you provided a body or what your request is. Please post more !

Comment: @trichetriche, sorry was a bit pressed for time. Added the code that sends the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue using the responseType header, as well as using the file-saver npm package. This solution is viable at the moment, but since this is user selected data, the filesize might become massive...

```
  ...post(url, send,
        { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`, 'Content-Type': contentType  }), observe: 'response', responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe(r => { saveAs(new Blob([r.body], { type: 'text/csv' }), 'download.csv')});
```